# get last level category name of a product in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to get only which category name that assigned a product and which category's have not any sub-category.

E.g :

```
Category
                -> Sub-category 1
                -> Sub-category 2
                -> Sub-category 3 
                                  -> Sub-sub-category 1
                                  -> sub-Sub-category 2
                                                        -> product 1
                                                        -> product 2
```

The above example , I want to get only **sub-sub-category 2**.

Comment: how did you get the category name for the specific product? Actually I am new to Magento, I am unable to understand the accept answer

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23744032/magento-get-specific-category-name-from-product-id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
 $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addIsActiveFilter()
                   ->addAttributeToFilter('level',3)
```