# How to get last level category of each product in magento

Tags: categories, product, magento-1.9

I am trying to get last level category name with its product count for each product on listing page. explained as below-

```
Category
                -> Sub-category 1
                          ->Sub-sub-category 11   -> Product 1
                          ->Sub-sub-category 12 
                              -> Sub-sub-sub-category 13  ->Product 2  
                -> Sub-category 2
                          ->Sub-sub-category 21 
                              -> Sub-sub-sub-category 22  ->Product 3 
                          ->Sub-sub-category 23   -> Product 4
```

I want to get  only categories "**Sub-sub-category 11**", "**Sub-sub-sub-category 13**", "**Sub-sub-sub-category 22**" and "**Sub-sub-category 23**" which are the last level categories of Products 1, Products 2, Products 3, Products 4.
I found below link [get last level category name of a product in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926118/get-last-level-category-name-of-a-product-in-magento) but it only gets third level category.

Answer (score 5):

A little late, but this can be accomplished very simply, use this function when you want to get the category of the deepest level for a given product :

```php
public function getProductLastLevelCategory(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product)
{
    /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Collection $categories */
    $categories = $product->getCategoryCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addOrder('level');

   return $categories->getFirstItem();
}
```

The base collection contains all the categories the given product belongs to, and the trick relies on sorting them by level (implicitly DESC).

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use the method `getChildrenCount()` for your category and check if it's equal to 0

```
if($category->getChildrenCount() == 0) {
  // Do something
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

at my problem i try this code and success

```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/category');
$_storeCategories = $_helper->getStoreCategories();
?>

<?php
function getLastCategory($_categories)
{
    $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
    if (count($_categories) > 0) {
        foreach ($_categories as $_category) {
            $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
            $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories();
            if (count($_subcategories) > 0) {
                getLastCategory($_subcategories);
            } else {
                echo($_category->getName()."<br />" );
            }
        }
    }
}

$lastCategory = getLastCategory($_storeCategories);
?>
```